# Loop background job

Tags: bash

I try to run a background job in a for loop in bash:

```
for i in $(seq 3); do echo $i ; sleep 2 & ; done
```

I get error:

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `;'
```

In zsh the command line works.

Comment: Which bit are you trying to place in background? as that reads you're trying to do the sleep in background which would be pointless..

Comment: sleep is only to test my loop before the real case.

Answer (score 171, accepted):

Remove the ; after sleep

```
for i in $(seq 3); do echo $i ; sleep 2 & done
```

BTW, such loops are better written on separate lines with proper indentation (if you are writing this in a shell script file).

```
for i in $(seq 3)
do
   echo $i
   sleep 2 &
done
```

Comment: Keep in mind that it will send "sleep 2" to background only.

Comment: Why is it when I do this with `$i` in the backgrounded command, job control says the process name contains `$i` instead of whatever the actual value of `$i` was?

Comment: @Michael Full program with output would help to understand better

Comment: `for I in <whatever>; do rm -fr $I & done` ... `jobs` -> `rm -fr $I` several times, instead of the actual dir being deleted for each job

Comment: I have answer for this, its long. So i think you should post it as a new question (and add that question link here), I will answer and you will also get more responses.

Answer (score 51):

You can put the background command in ( )

```
for i in $(seq 3); do echo $i ; (sleep 2 &) ; done
```

Comment: Please be aware: You create a subshell by that. It also means you will not be able to `wait` for the background jobs to end.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to run a block of code in the background, you could do the below. Just put the block of code around the curly braces.

```
{ for i in $(seq 3); do echo $i ; sleep 2 ; done } &
```