# bash script to run a constant number of jobs in the background

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I need a bash script to run some jobs in the background, three jobs at a time.

I know can do this in the following way, and for illustration, I will assume the number of jobs is 6:

```
./j1 &
./j2 &
./j3 &
wait
./j4 &
./j5 &
./j6 &
wait
```

However, this way, if, for example, j2 takes a lot longer to run that j1 and j3, then, I will be stuck with only one background job running for a long time.

The alternative (which is what I want) is that whenever one job is completed, bash should start the next job in the queue so that a rate of 3 jobs at any given time is maintained. Is it possible to write a bash script to implement this alternative, possibly using a loop? Please note that I need to run far more jobs, and I expect this alternative method to save me a lot of time.

Here is my draft of the script, which I hope you can help me to verify its correctness and improve it, as I'm new to scripting in bash. The ideas in this script are taken and modified from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12472933/loop-background-job), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131484/wait-for-bash-background-jobs-in-script-to-be-finished), and [here](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO.html)):

```
for i in $(seq 6)
do
   # wait here if the number of jobs is 3 (or more)
   while (( (( $(jobs -p | wc -l) )) >= 3 )) 
   do 
      sleep 5      # check again after 5 seconds
   done

   jobs -x ./j$i &
done
wait
```

IMHO, I think this script does the required behavior. However, I need to know -from bash experts- if I'm doing something wrong or if there is a better way of implementing this idea.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Which version of bash, *specifically*?

Comment: BTW, `seq` is generally bad form. It's not specified by POSIX and also not built into bash, so there's no particular reason to believe it'll be present on a given system. Use a [C-style `for` loop](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/ccmd/c_for) instead

Comment: ...to be specific as to why I asked about the version -- modern bash has a `wait -n` flag that waits for only one job to exit.

Comment: (Personally, I'm wary of relying on big chunks of perl, so I use the smaller, simpler and admittedly-less-capable `xargs -P` rather than parallel. That said, positions do differ on that count).

Comment: Charles: GNU bash, version 4.3.46(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

Comment: Then you've got `wait -n`, making your life very easy.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy does that help though? You don't know which job is going to finish first, you might end up waiting for a job to finish while other jobs have already finished. You want a poll, or a wait with a timeout.

Comment: @SpoonMeiser, it waits for *any* job to exit, not a specific one. That's the whole purpose of having `wait -n`, as opposed to `wait "$somepid"`

Comment: chepner: parallel is not installed in my system, and unfortunately, I don't have permissions to install packages.

Comment: Yeah, I misread the docs. Ignore me.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Can you please elaborate how to use this wait -n in my case? Maybe how to use it in a script?

Comment: BTW, folks interested in this question should probably read [ProcessManagement](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessManagement).

Comment: You don't need to install any packages to run `parallel` - it is just a Perl script (like one you might write yourself) and IMHO it is almost certainly the best, and simplest, way to run your jobs - especially if the duration varies wildly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With GNU xargs:

```
printf '%s\0' j{1..6} | xargs -0 -n1 -P3 sh -c './"$1"' _
```

---

With bash (4.x) builtins:

```
max_jobs=3; cur_jobs=0
for ((i=0; i<6; i++)); do
  # If true, wait until the next background job finishes to continue.
  ((cur_jobs >= max_jobs)) && wait -n
  # Increment the current number of jobs running.
  ./j"$i" & ((++cur_jobs))
done
wait
```

Note that the approach relying on builtins has some corner cases -- if you have multiple jobs exiting at the exact same time, a single `wait -n` can reap several of them, thus effectively consuming multiple slots. If we wanted to be more robust, we might end up with something like the following:

```
max_jobs=3
declare -A cur_jobs=( ) # build an associative array w/ PIDs of jobs we started
for ((i=0; i<6; i++)); do
  if (( ${#cur_jobs[@]} >= max_jobs )); then
    wait -n # wait for at least one job to exit
    # ...and then remove any jobs that aren't running from the table
    for pid in "${!cur_jobs[@]}"; do
      kill -0 "$pid" 2>/dev/null && unset cur_jobs[$pid]
    done
  fi
  ./j"$i" & cur_jobs[$!]=1
done
wait
```

...which is obviously a lot of work, and still has a minor race. Consider using `xargs -P` instead. :)

Comment: Your first `bash` loop never decrements `curr_jobs`, nor can it effectively.

Comment: @chepner, it doesn't need to do a decrement. We're just making sure that after we've started three, we have one to reap for every additional one we start. If you care about the case when `wait -n` is actually reaping more than one job... that's what the second version is for.

Answer (score 4):

Using GNU Parallel:

```
parallel -j3 ::: ./j{1..6}
```

Or if your shell does not do .. expansion (e.g. csh):

```
seq 6 | parallel -j3 ./j'{}'
```

If you think you cannot install GNU Parallel, please read http://oletange.blogspot.dk/2013/04/why-not-install-gnu-parallel.html and leave a comment on why you cannot install it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could assist..

**Sample usecase**: run 'sleep 20' 30 times, just as an example. It could be any job or another script. Our control logic is to keep checking whether "how many already fired?" is less than or equal to "max processes defined", inside a while loop. If not, fire one and if yes, sleep .5 seconds.

Script output: In the below snip, it is observed that now we have 30 'sleep 20' commands running in the background, as we configured max=30.

```
%_Host@User> ps -ef|grep 'sleep 20'|grep -v grep|wc -l
30
%_Host@User>
```

*Change value of no. of jobs at runtime*: Script has a param "max", which takes value from a file "max.txt"(`max=$(cat max.txt)`) and then applies it in each iteration of the while loop. As seen below, we changed it to 45 and now we have 45 'sleep 20' commands running in the background. You can put the main script in background and just keep changing the max value inside "`max.txt`" to control.

```
%_Host@User> cat > max.txt
45
^C
%_Host@User> ps -ef|grep 'sleep 20'|grep -v grep|wc -l
45
%_Host@User>
```

**Script:**

```
#!/bin/bash
#---------------------------------------------------------------------#
proc='sleep 20' # Your process or script or anything..
max=$(cat max.txt)  # configure how many jobs do you want
curr=0
#---------------------------------------------------------------------#
while true
do
  curr=$(ps -ef|grep "$proc"|grep -v grep|wc -l); max=$(cat max.txt)
  while [[ $curr -lt $max ]]
        do
    ${proc} &        # Sending process to background.
    max=$(cat max.txt) # After sending one job, again calculate max and curr
    curr=$(ps -ef|grep "$proc"|grep -v grep|wc -l)
  done
  sleep .5    # sleep .5 seconds if reached max jobs.
done
#---------------------------------------------------------------------#
```

Let us know if it was any useful.

Comment: `${proc} &` has all the bugs described in [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Comment: ...there are a number of other issues here as well. Many processes spawn subshells -- if you spawn a script that runs two subshells, then every directly-spawned copy will count as three in your `wc -l`. The `ps` approach counts not just direct children of this job, but all processes across the entire system. Not all jobs match themselves as a regex -- if you run `find '/incoming/[a-zA-Z]*.d' -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -exec my-process`, then the `[a-zA-Z]` in the grep won't match the `[` character in the associated position in the ps output.

Comment: Thanks Charles. I am gonna check what you said, hopefully learn something new. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it:

1. Enable jobs in our script:

   ```
   set -m
   ```
2. Create a trap which kills all jobs if the script is interrupted:

   ```
   trap 'jobs -p | xargs kill 2>/dev/null;' EXIT
   ```
3. Use a loop to start a maximum of 3 jobs in background

   ```
   for i in $(seq 6); do
     while [[ $(jobs | wc -l) -ge 3 ]]; do
       sleep 5
     done
     ./j"$i" &
   done
   ```
4. Finally bring our background jobs back to the foreground:

   ```
   while fg >/dev/null 2>&1; do
     echo -n "" # output nothing
   done
   ```

Because of the last part the script does not exit as long jobs are running and it avoids that jobs get killed by `trap`.

Answer (score 0):

#### How to run constant number of parallel tasks, using [bash](/questions/tagged/bash)

From version 5.1-alpha of [bash](/questions/tagged/bash):

> This document details the changes between this version, bash-5.1-alpha, and
> the previous version, bash-5.0-release.
> ...
> q. wait: has a new -p VARNAME option, which stores the PID returned by `wait -n` or `wait` without arguments.

Some relevant parts from `help wait`:

```
wait: wait [-fn] [-p var] [id ...]
    Wait for job completion and return exit status.
    ...
    If the -n option is supplied, waits for a single job from ... and returns its 
    exit status.

    If the -p option is supplied, the process or job identifier of the job
    for which the exit status is returned is assigned to the variable VAR
    named by the option argument. The variable will be unset initially, before
    any assignment. This is useful only when the -n option is supplied.
```

#### Some tests

```bash
dummyTest() {
    sleep $((1+RANDOM%2)).$RANDOM # Sleep something between 1.0 and 2.999 seconds
    return $((RANDOM%2))          # Return either 0 or 1
}

dummyTest & wait -np myvar;myres=$?
[1] 1578088
[1]+  Done                    dummyTest
echo $myvar $myres
1578088 0

dummyTest & wait -np myvar;myres=$?
[1] 1579320
[1]+  Exit 1                  dummyTest
echo $myvar $myres
1579320 1
```

#### Running this 20 time with max 5 concurrent parallel tasks.

```bash
time {
    declare -a pids=() results=()
    for i in {1..20};do
        dummyTest &
        pids[$!]=''
        if (( ${#pids[@]} > 4 )); then 
           wait -np epid
           results[epid]=$?
           unset pids[epid]
        fi
    done; while (( ${#pids[@]} )); do
        wait -np epid
        results[epid]=$?
        unset pids[epid]
    done; declare -p pids results
 }
```

could produce something like:

```
[1] 7656
[2] 7657
[3] 7659
[4] 7660
[5] 7662
[3]   Done                    dummyTest
[6] 7666
....
[13]   Exit 1                  dummyTest
[19] 7694
[16]   Done                    dummyTest
[20] 7697
[15]   Exit 1                  dummyTest
[17]   Done                    dummyTest
[18]   Done                    dummyTest
[19]-  Done                    dummyTest
[20]+  Done                    dummyTest
declare -a pids=()
declare -a results=([7656]="0" [7657]="0" [7659]="0" [7660]="0" [7662]="0" [7666
]="0" [7668]="0" [7671]="0" [7673]="0" [7675]="0" [7677]="1" [7680]="0" [7682]="
1" [7684]="0" [7686]="1" [7688]="0" [7690]="0" [7692]="0" [7694]="0" [7697]="0")

real    0m8.256s
user    0m0.147s
sys     0m0.203s
```

#### Addressing precisely you request:

For this, quickly create a script:

```bash
cat >dummyTest.sh <<"eof"
#!/bin/bash
sleep $((1+RANDOM%2)).$RANDOM
exit $((RANDOM%2))
eof
chmod +x dummyTest.sh
for i in j{1..6};do
    ln -s dummyTest.sh $i
done
```

So you wanna run all executable files matching `./j?`

```bash
#!/bin/bash
scripts=(./j{1..6})
maxProc=3
declare -a pids=() results=()
for script in ${scripts[@]};do
    $script &
    pids[$!]='' sname[$!]="${script#./}"
    IFS=. read -r sec mus <<<$EPOCHREALTIME
    printf '%(%a %d %T)T.%s : start %s\n' "$sec" "$mus" "$script"
    if (( ${#pids[@]} >= $maxProc )); then 
       wait -np epid
       results[epid]=$?
       unset pids[epid]
    fi
done
while (( ${#pids[@]} )); do
    wait -np epid
    results[epid]=$?
    unset pids[epid]
done
for i in ${!sname[@]};do
    printf 'Tool \47%s\47 ended with %d\n' ${sname[i]} ${results[i]}
done
```

May output:

```
Mon 22 09:36:27.639958 : start ./j1
Mon 22 09:36:27.640227 : start ./j2
Mon 22 09:36:27.640431 : start ./j3
Mon 22 09:36:29.801544 : start ./j4
Mon 22 09:36:30.162347 : start ./j5
Mon 22 09:36:30.934706 : start ./j6
Tool 'j1' ended with 0
Tool 'j2' ended with 0
Tool 'j3' ended with 0
Tool 'j4' ended with 1
Tool 'j5' ended with 0
Tool 'j6' ended with 0
```

#### Same, with more stats:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
scripts=(./j{1..6})
maxProc=3
declare -a pids=() results=()
wait1pid() {
    local epid
    wait -np epid
    results[epid]=$?
    ends[epid]=$EPOCHREALTIME
    unset pids[epid]
}
for script in ${scripts[@]}; do
    $script &
    pids[$!]='' sname[$!]="${script#./}" starts[$!]=$EPOCHREALTIME
    (( ${#pids[@]} >= $maxProc )) && wait1pid
done
while (( ${#pids[@]} )); do
    wait1pid                  
done
for i in ${!sname[@]}; do
    elap=0000$(( ${ends[i]/.} - ${starts[i]/.} ))
    printf -v elap '%.5f' ${elap::-6}.${elap: -6}
    printf 'Tool: \47%s\47, start %(%a %d %T)T.%s, elaps: %s end with %d.\n' \
        "${sname[i]}" ${starts[i]%.*} ${starts[i]#*.} $elap ${results[i]}
done
```

Could produce:

```
Tool: 'j1', start Mon 22 10:17:19.969397, elaps: 2.11891 end with 1.
Tool: 'j2', start Mon 22 10:17:19.969575, elaps: 2.17050 end with 1.
Tool: 'j3', start Mon 22 10:17:19.969736, elaps: 2.26674 end with 0.
Tool: 'j4', start Mon 22 10:17:22.088857, elaps: 2.19518 end with 0.
Tool: 'j5', start Mon 22 10:17:22.140655, elaps: 1.18759 end with 0.
Tool: 'j6', start Mon 22 10:17:22.236791, elaps: 1.18076 end with 1.
```

#### With STDOUT and STDERR driven

```bash
#!/bin/bash
maxProc=3
declare -ai outFds=() errFds=() pids=() results=()
declare -a outputs=() errmsgs=()
run1pid() {
    local -i scOut sPid scErr
    printf '%s..\r' >&2 "$1"
    exec {scOut}<> <(:)
    exec {scErr}<> <(:)
    "$@" >&$scOut 2>&$scErr &
    sPid=$!
    starts[sPid]=$EPOCHREALTIME
    pids[sPid]=     outFds[sPid]=scOut    errFds[sPid]=scErr
    sname[sPid]="${*#./}"
}
wait1pid() {
    local epid line
    wait -np epid
    results[epid]=$?
    local -i epidOut=${outFds[epid]} epidErr=${errFds[epid]}
    ends[epid]=$EPOCHREALTIME
    while read -ru $epidErr -t 0 line; do
        read -ru $epidErr line 
        errmsgs[epid]+="$line"$'\n'
    done
    while read -ru $epidOut -t 0 line; do
        read -ru $epidOut line 
        outputs[epid]+="$line"$'\n'
    done
    outputs[epid]=${outputs[epid]%$'\n'} errmsgs[epid]=${errmsgs[epid]%$'\n'}
    exec {epidOut}<&-; exec {epidErr}<&-
    unset pids[epid] outFds[epid] errFds[epid]
}
```

```bash
scripts=("$@")
# Parallelize $scripts uptu max $maxProc 
for script in ${scripts[@]}; do
    run1pid "$script"
    (( ${#pids[@]} >= $maxProc )) && wait1pid
done
# Wait for remaining pids
while (( ${#pids[@]} )); do
    wait1pid                  
done

# Show results and commands's outputs dimmed and commands's errors in bold
for i in ${!sname[@]}; do
    elap=0000$(( ${ends[i]/.} - ${starts[i]/.} ))
    printf -v elap '%.6f' ${elap::-6}.${elap: -6}
    printf 'Tool: \47%s\47, start %(%a %d %T)T.%s, elaps: %s end with %d.\n' \
           "${sname[i]}" ${starts[i]%.*} ${starts[i]#*.} $elap ${results[i]}
    [[ ${outputs[i]} ]] && printf '\e[2m  - %s\e[0m\n' "${outputs[i]//$'\n'/$'\n  - '}"
    [[ ${errmsgs[i]} ]] && printf '\e[1m  - %s\e[0m\n' "${errmsgs[i]//$'\n'/$'\n  - '}"
done
```

For testing this, my *`testscript`* has evolved, they print out on `STDOUT` if exit with `0` and on `STDERR` if exit with `1`, could sometime add one more line on `STDOUT`.

```bash
#!/bin/bash
sleepSec=$((1+RANDOM%2)).$RANDOM
exitStat=$((RANDOM%2))
statStr=(succeed fail)
((RANDOM%2)) &&
    echo "Some string could appear (from $$)."
sleep $sleepSec
printf 'Process %s did sleep %f sec, then %s.\n' \
    "${0##*/}" "$sleepSec" "${statStr[exitStat]}" >&$((1+exitStat))
exit $exitStat
```

Then `for testfile in j{1..8};do ln -s testscript.sh $testfile;done`

```
$ ./myParSript.sh ./j?
Tool: 'j1', start Mon 22 19:10:28.513917, elaps: 1.145942 end with 1.
  - Process j1 did sleep 1.143330 sec, then fail.
Tool: 'j2', start Mon 22 19:10:28.514743, elaps: 1.454796 end with 1.
  - Process j2 did sleep 1.451500 sec, then fail.
Tool: 'j3', start Mon 22 19:10:28.515355, elaps: 1.185490 end with 0.
  - Some string could appear (from 2373802).
  - Process j3 did sleep 1.181490 sec, then succeed.
Tool: 'j4', start Mon 22 19:10:29.660715, elaps: 2.504456 end with 0.
  - Process j4 did sleep 2.502000 sec, then succeed.
Tool: 'j5', start Mon 22 19:10:29.701745, elaps: 2.202175 end with 1.
  - Some string could appear (from 2373862).
  - Process j5 did sleep 2.199700 sec, then fail.
Tool: 'j6', start Mon 22 19:10:29.970374, elaps: 1.289719 end with 0.
  - Some string could appear (from 2373892).
  - Process j6 did sleep 1.286250 sec, then succeed.
Tool: 'j7', start Mon 22 19:10:31.261612, elaps: 1.289405 end with 1.
  - Process j7 did sleep 1.285560 sec, then fail.
Tool: 'j8', start Mon 22 19:10:31.905393, elaps: 1.258086 end with 1.
  - Some string could appear (from 2373965).
  - Process j8 did sleep 1.254720 sec, then fail.
```

#### Other samples

- For speeding up `rsync` as [Speed up rsync with Simultaneous/Concurrent File Transfers?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72480364/1765658)
- On [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77803372/1765658), I build a script to run parallelized *GitHub CLI* `gh repo clone "$repo"` for all entries from `gh repo list myorgname`
- For fun, I ran *shellcheck* on a whole directory in parallel, with max `$numproc`. ( From this [comment on *GNU Parallel with shellcheck on multiple files*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51035770/gnu-parallel-with-shellcheck-on-multiple-files/51039001#comment137249730_51039001) to ) this full [parShellCheck.sh](https://f-hauri.ch/vrac/parShellCheck.sh.txt) script. In this sample script, **the outputs of parallelized commands are driven into main script to be printed out in correct order**.