# GNU Parallel with shellcheck on multiple files

Tags: bash, gnu-parallel, shellcheck

How do I use GNU Parallel to run shellcheck on all *.sh with a wrapper function?

This attempt has the correct target files, but Parallel seems to struggle with the subshell.

```
lint:sh() {
  local output
  targets=$(find . -name '*.sh' -exec echo {} \;)
  output=$(parallel --no-notice shellcheck ::: "$targets")
  results $? "$output"
}
```

Comment: I think you want `targets` to be an array. `targets=($(find ...))` then pass `”${targets[@]}` to **GNU Parallel**

Comment: `find ... -exec echo {} \;` seems overly verbose - try omitting `-exec` and everything after.

Comment: When using an array (verbose is not he current issue) `mapfile -t targets < <(find . -name '*.sh' -exec echo {} \;) output=$(parallel --no-notice shellcheck ::: "${targets[@]}")` i get a non-zero exit but in the subshell not, lint:sh - results is not invoked

Comment: And its it is invoking the targets rather than passing them to shellcheck

Comment: I don't think a colon is permitted in a function name, btw.

Comment: I don't think the : name space delim is the issue in this post but I can use _  instead, especially if that is more typical for shell scripts

Answer (score 1):

Use the following approach:

```
lint:sh() {
  local output
  output=$(find . -name "*.sh" -print0 | parallel -q0 --no-notice shellcheck)
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this bites both problems of  eating the error codes and the output.

Comment: @Tom, the goal was to show you a working GNU parallel approach. But `results` is your custom "feature". Consider my approach to only this line `output=$(find . -name "*.sh" -print0 | parallel -q0 --no-notice shellcheck)`

Comment: That line exits 1 and kills the wrapper script - so results is never invoked. I also can not `echo $output` instead of ` results ...` Using std in vs redirect with ::: does not seem to be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

due to different flaws in bash the safiest way may be

```
targets=()
while read -r -d '' file; [[ $file ]]; do
    targets+=("$file");
done < <(find . -name '*.sh' -print0)
```

also because `targets` type was changed to array

```
output=$(parallel --no-notice shellcheck ::: "${targets[@]}")
```

Comment: Using bash's globstar `**/*.sh` would be way easier.

Comment: @Socowi, but would present a serious drawback because `**` would expand in memory and would be much slower.

Comment: Slower, yes (on my system by factor 3.5 for `/**/*.so`) but the memory argument doesn't count here. In both cases, all files are stored in an array which is stored in memory.

Comment: You could do simpler :  `mapfile -d '' -t targets < <(find /tmp/so -type f -print0)`!

Comment: I've built a [*pure bash* *`parallel shellcheck`*](https://f-hauri.ch/vrac/parShellCheck.sh.txt), with cleaner output, Seem quicker than using `parallel!`! Please, have a try!