# Why use the underscore as an argument to read in bash?

Tags: bash

I recently found a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19576742/how-to-clone-all-repos-at-once-from-github) about how to clone all repos from an org In GitHub. The top answer was the following:

```
gh repo list myorgname --limit 4000 | while read -r repo _; do
  gh repo clone "$repo" "$repo"
done
```

I understand everything before and after the underscore. What is the meaning of  _; in the above command?

Thanks!

Comment: Technically, it's a *"thing you can't be bothered to think up a name for"*, i.e. a variable you don't plan to use.

Comment: See the Special Parameters section of `man bash` for *a* special meaning for `_`, but in this case it's just being used as a regular parameter name. Conventionally, it means you won't be using whatever value you assigned to it, so you give it a name that won't distract you while reading the rest of the code.

Comment: In this specific case, you could also massage the `gh` command to print just the name to begin with:  `gh repo list --json name --jq 'map(.name)[]'`

Comment: assume you feed `arg1 arg2 ... argN` to the `while/read` loop; `repo` is set to `arg1` while `_` is assigned everything else; you could accomplish the same thing with a differently named variable (eg, `while read -r repo rest_of_line`); while `_` does have a special meaning in `bash`, in this case it's also used to a) capture everything after `arg1` and b) used to indicate that everything after `arg1` is going to be ignored

Comment: The use of `_` with `read` is explained in [BashFAQ/001 (How can I read a file \(data stream, variable\) line-by-line \(and/or field-by-field)?)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001).  Also see [Understand the meaning of `$_`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/280453/264812).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Variable `_` is used as a *garbage*

From `man bash` (or `man -P'less +"/^ *Shell Variables"' bash`):

> ```
> Shell Variables
>     The following variables are set by the shell:
>
>     _      At  shell  startup, set to the pathname used to invoke the shell
>            or shell script being executed as passed in the  environment  or
>            argument  list.   Subsequently,  expands to the last argument to
>            the previous simple command executed in  the  foreground,  after
>            expansion.   Also  set  to the full pathname used to invoke each
>            command executed and placed in the environment exported to  that
>            command.   When  checking mail, this parameter holds the name of
>            the mail file currently being checked.
> ```

This variable will hold the last *argument* of previous line.

##### Little useful case

I ofen use this:

```bash
mkdir -p /some/path/somewhere
cd $_
```

##### Unusable in other way

If you try to use them as a variable, you may become disapointed

```bash
_='Hello world!'
echo "I said: '$_'"
```

```
I said: ''
```

Then (`:` in an alias for `true`)

```bash
: "Not this"
echo "I said: '$_'"
```

```
I said: 'Not this'
```

But if you repeat last command

```bash
echo "I said: '$_'"
```

```
I said: 'I said: 'Not this''
```

##### Used as a *trashcan*

But in your sample, they are used as a ***garbage***:

So `while read -r repo _;...` will parse each line of input by storing first (*space separated*)  word into `$repo` and *the rest of line* into (unusable) `$_`.

Sample,showing your *GECOS* field from your password file:

```bash
while IFS=: read -r user _ uid _ gecos ;do
    (( UID == uid )) && echo $user ${gecos%%,*}
done < /etc/passwd
```

##### About your sample using `gh repo list`

I prefer to write this in the other way, this will permit to use *overall* variable in order to create stats and other reusable things:

```bash
declare -i cloned=0 total=0
while read -r repo _; do
    total+=1
    gh repo clone "$repo" "$repo" &&
        cloned+=1
done < <(
    gh repo list myorgname --limit 4000
)
printf 'There was %d repo successfully cloned, over %d total\n' \
    $cloned $total
```

You may found more sample at [How do I set a variable to the output of a command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41236640/1765658)

#### But as [*TIMTOWTDI*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/TMTOWTDI)

You could *read* your `gh repo list`  into an *array* before processing elements:

```bash
mapfile -t rList < <(gh repo list myorgname --limit 4000)
declare -i cloned=0 total=${#rList[@]}
printf 'There are %d objects to clone.\n' $total
for repo in "${rList[@]/%$'\11'*}"; do
    gh repo clone "$repo" "$repo" &&
        cloned+=1
done
printf 'There was %d repo successfully cloned, over %d total\n' \
    $cloned $total
```

For sample, you could plan to download simultaneously upto 5 process at a time:

#### Parallel `gh` clone full *demo* script.

(Copied from [Speed up rsync with Simultaneous/Concurrent File Transfers?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72480364/1765658).)

Save this as `gh_parClone.sh` and give him execution right:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

maxProc=5
[[ $1 == -v ]] && verbose=1 && shift || verbose=0
orgName="$1"

declare -ai start elap results order
declare -a succeeded failed messages
wait4oneTask() {
    printf 'Running task: %d\r' ${#running[@]}
    wait -np epid
    results[epid]=$?
    local _i _line
    elap[epid]=" ${EPOCHREALTIME/.} - ${start[epid]} "
    if ((results[epid])); then
        failed[epid]="${repos[epid]}"
    else
        succeeded[epid]="${repos[epid]}"
    fi
    
    while read -ru "${ghFds[epid]}" -t .02 _line; do
        messages[epid]+="$_line"$'\n'
    done
    exec {ghFds[epid]}<&-
    unset "ghFds[epid]"
    unset "running[$epid]"
    while [[ -v elap[${order[0]}] ]]; do
        _i=${order[0]}
        printf " - %(%a %d %T)T.%06.0f %-36s %4d %12d\n" "${start[_i]:0:-6}" \
               "${start[_i]: -6}" "${repos[_i]}" "${results[_i]}" "${elap[_i]}"
        order=("${order[@]:1}")
    done
}
```

```bash
mapfile -t rList < <(LANG=C gh repo list "$orgName")
printf 'GH: %d object in \47%s\47. Start clone with max %d instances.\n' \
       ${#rList[@]} "$orgName" $maxProc

printf "   %-22s %-36s %4s %12s\n" Started Repo Rslt 'microseconds'
for repo in "${rList[@]/%$'\11'*}"; do
    exec {ghFd}<> <(:)
    gh repo clone "$repo"{,} >&$ghFd 2>&1 &
    lpid=$!
    ghFds[lpid]=$ghFd
    repos[lpid]="${repo#$orgName/}" 
    start[lpid]=${EPOCHREALTIME/.}
    running[lpid]=''
    order+=("$lpid")
    ((${#running[@]}>=maxProc)) && wait4oneTask
done
while ((${#running[@]})); do
    wait4oneTask
done
printf 'Succeeded: %d.\n%s\n' ${#succeeded[@]} "${succeeded[*]}"
if ((verbose)); then
    for pid in "${!succeeded[@]}"; do
    printf ' - %s\n' "${succeeded[pid]}"
    printf '       %s\n' "${messages[pid]//$'\n'/$'\n'       }"
    done
fi
printf 'Failed: %d.\n' ${#failed[@]}
if ((${#failed[@]})); then
    for pid in "${!failed[@]}"; do
        printf ' - %s\n' "${failed[pid]}"
        printf '       %s\n' "${messages[pid]//$'\n'/$'\n'       }"
    done
fi
```

Sample run:

```
$ mkdir -p demos/mixxx/foo
$ ./gh_parClone.sh demos
GH: 9 object in 'demos'. Start clone with max 5 instances.
   Started                Repo                                 Rslt microseconds
 - Fri 12 10:41:59.476735 php-logical-filter                      0      2100719
 - Fri 12 10:41:59.477372 mixxx                                   1       403229
 - Fri 12 10:41:59.477718 Cache                                   0      2062995
 - Fri 12 10:41:59.478078 developer_skins                         0      3713021
 - Fri 12 10:41:59.478470 Qt-Inspector                            0      1949781
 - Fri 12 10:41:59.901984 pytaglib                                0      2325354
 - Fri 12 10:42:01.449372 gmap3                                   0      2269148
 - Fri 12 10:42:01.561883 Motif                                   0      4105144
 - Fri 12 10:42:01.600549 offlineimap                             0      4493532
Succeeded: 8.
php-logical-filter Cache developer_skins Qt-Inspector pytaglib gmap3 Motif offlineimap
Failed: 1.
 - mixxx
       fatal: destination path 'demos/mixxx' already exists and is not an empty directory.
       failed to run git: exit status 128
```

Longer output if run with `-v` flag:

```
$ ./gh_parClone.sh -v demos
```

Comment: Added a full sample script for *parallelized download*.